# How to give lines plotted with ParametricPlot3D more of thick, 3D look?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I would like to plot some curves in 3D, but the default style of lines in ParametricPlot3D is pretty flat.
Is there a way to give them more of a 3D look? (think a pipe or a noodle instead of a wire).

for example, my plot looks  [image: like this]

but i would like the blue and purple curves to look more like the purple lines here [image: this plot]

(From [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphoton.2010.259/))

Comment: Try `PlotStyle -> {{Purple, Tube[.2]}, {Blue, Tube[.2]}}`?

Comment: @kglr Works beautifully, thanks. (0.2 thickness was huge for my plot though. used 0.01)